# Uploading a file to AppEngine using GWT: How to provide feedback to the user?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, upload, feedback, formpanel

I have a GWT-FormPanel on my website, where people can upload pictures and answer some questions. It's working very well. The only problem is: I would like to provide a feedback to the user (for example: 0% to 100%) during the actual file process. But I have no idea how I can do that. I think that's a very common issue, that's why I would like to ask you guys if you know any tutorial or example that could help me to solve this problem.

I've already tried [GWTUpload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/), but it does not do what I want: I have a submit button at the end of the FormPanel and the GWTUpload has it's own "SEND" button, which I don't want to have.

Thanks in advance for helping and merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [GWTUpload allows to use custom submit button](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/source/browse/trunk/GwtUpload/core/src/main/java/gwtupload/client/SingleUploader.java?r=812#93). Haven't tried it so maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: No, you aren't! Have just tried and it works. thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 2):

From your problem statement you mean to say that you want to provide the progress bar while uploading file starting from 0 to 100%.

Take a look to this library: http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/. This will may solve your problem.And it is also working well in all browsers and also on Linux,Mac.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I wrote on my post, I can't attach a GWTUpload element (for example: a SingleUploader widget) cause it has it's own "SEND" button. And I don't want to have. At the end of my formular (FormPanel) I have a Submit button, that should fire the upload of the pictures (As a POST Request). So, it does not fit to my design. Thanks anyway for answering! Would appreciate any further suggestion.